# Disabling neighbour solicitation

Tags: contiki, iot

I would like to disable the neighbour advertisement and neighbour solicitation in contiki. What is the configuration that needs to be disabled in the config file of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variable `UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_NA` to 0.